# watchInternal is not a function in react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm getting an error while using `react-hook-form` *7.8.2*, I used `useWatch` in one of my components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to update to the latest version of `react-hook-form`.(at this moment *7.25.0*)
I couldn't find the reason. I'm just leaving this here for those who came across this weird error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, that package wasn't installed